# How to share @Before and @Test among classes in Selenium 2?

Tags: java, selenium

I've the following two methods in all my classes:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {      
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    String baseUrl = "http://trn-test-web.fon.com/";
    selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, baseUrl);
}

@Test
public void firstTest() throws Exception{
    selenium.open("/opencase/login.seam");
    selenium.type("//input[contains(@id, ':username')]", "admin");
    selenium.type("//input[contains(@id,':mypassword')]", "admin");
    selenium.click("//a[contains(@id,'loginForm:')]/span");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("60000");        
    _wait("Home", "id=oc-title-id");
}
```

How can I share the `@Before` and `@Test` methods with other classes in a project so they will not open their own login page and use the same `baseUrl` and login amongst the classes?

Answer (score 3):

You can make class (TestBase) that will be extend by your tests

```
public class TestBase {

    protected WebDriver driver;
    protected Selenium selenium

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {      
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    String baseUrl = "http://trn-test-web.fon.com/";
    selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, baseUrl);
}

@Test
public void firstTest() throws Exception{
    selenium.open("/opencase/login.seam");
    selenium.type("//input[contains(@id, ':username')]", "admin");
    selenium.type("//input[contains(@id,':mypassword')]", "admin");
    selenium.click("//a[contains(@id,'loginForm:')]/span");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("60000");        
    _wait("Home", "id=oc-title-id");
}
```

Here how to use it

```
public class ExampleTest extends TestBase {

@Test
public void secondTest() throws Exception {
     selenium.open("http://stackoverflow.com/");
}
```

now every time you run class ExampleTest, it will run **firstTest** and **secondTest**

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to put the @Before method in a abstract class, something like `AbstractUITest` and make all of your tests to inherit from that class, that way every time the test runs, the @Before method is executed from the abstract class and all of them can use the baseUrl.